# Burninate [attach]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tags [attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attach) and [detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detach) seem to be very unfocused. Questions tagged cover a wide array of languages as well as meanings of the word.

Comment: Attach some reason for attaching [attach] or you'll be attached.

Comment: @nicael: FTFY Attach some reason for attaching [attach] or you'll be [detach]ed.

Comment: Why, "attached" is good there... as unfocused as your question... ;-)

Comment: @nicael Updated

Comment: It amazes me how many tags exist as simply words that happen to be in the title of a question and have no other purpose in the context of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[attach] is burned. detach() is a common function in jQuery and appears to be used heavily for that purpose; it could probably use some cleanup, but it's a legit tag.